# Trying to change an event to preventDefault in Wordpress site using Joomla template

Tags: javascript, wordpress, joomla

I'm coding a Wordpress site using a Joomla template (client liked the template, so I'm converting to Wordpress). The problem I am having is that I want the background image caption to not show on load, but instead only show after clicking the link button.

This is the site that is functioning the way I would like: http://livedemo00.template-help.com/joomla_33451/index.php

Here is my Wordpress version: http://gt.khcreativemedia.com/

I believe I have all of the same code in place, javascript and css.

Here is the code that I believe is handling this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $j(function()
    {

    $j("#link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $j(this).toggleClass("link2");
    $j("#top_menu").slideToggle("slow");
    });
            })

</script>
```

I'm using a javascript gallery called jdgallery. Here is a reduced section of code from the image section:

```
<div class="jbgallery"> 
 <ul> 
   <li>
      <a title="" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/background/Auburn.jpg">1</a> 
      <div class="caption">Mauris pharetra lorem in velit scelerisque hendrerit. Etiam id sapien eros. Etiam ante velit, fermentum et
      </div> 
 </ul> 
</div><!-- #jbgallery -->
```

Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong.

Thanks in advance,
Keith

Comment: so where are you loading the background image?

Comment: I'm using a javascript gallery called jdgallery. Here is a reduced section of code from the image section:<div class="jbgallery">
  <ul>
   <li><a title="" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/background/Auburn.jpg">1</a>
   <div class="caption">Mauris pharetra lorem in velit scelerisque hendrerit. Etiam id sapien eros. Etiam ante velit, fermentum et</div>
  </ul>
 </div><!-- #jbgallery -->

Comment: maybe you should add the code snippet to your question instead. copy your comment, click on edit under your question and paste it there. and don't forget to format it, by pressing the {} in edit mode

Comment: Thanks Ibu. Guess it's obvious that I am a newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma. Replace

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".jbgallery").jbgallery({
        menu : "numbers", 
        style: "zoom", 
        caption : true,
        slideshow : true,
        labels   : {
            info : "I"
        }
        ready : function(){
            jQuery(".jbg-caption").hide();
        }


    });
});
```

with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".jbgallery").jbgallery({
        menu : "numbers", 
        style: "zoom", 
        caption : true,
        slideshow : true,
        labels   : {
            info : "I"
        },
        ready : function(){
            jQuery(".jbg-caption").hide();
        }


    });
});
```

Comment: Outstanding. That was the ticket. Thank you very much for your help. I'm an official fan of stacked overflow with all the knowledge that has been thrown at me.

Comment: @Keith Higginbotham: Glad it helped and if your question is now resolved, please mark this as the answer -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but if you want it not visible, you could add a call to `hide()` on the element on load, like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){
    // hide it first thing onload?
    $j("#top_menu").hide();

    $j("#link").bind('click', function(event) {
        $j(this).toggleClass("link2");
        $j("#top_menu").slideToggle("slow");
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Alternately, simply add `display: none` to the element's html:

```
<div id="top_menu" style="display: none">
```

Comment: Well, I'm honestly don't know where the #top_menu and #link even come into play. I have found them ONLY in the css. The class I'm actually trying to hide is .jbg-caption. I tried using your code with this class and no luck. <script type="text/javascript"><!--
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $j(function(){
     // hide it first thing onload?
     $j(".jbg-caption").hide();
 });
 --></script>